# Automate the creation of an instances of an object

Tags: javascript, html

I have an variable  which acts as a counter. I am trying to use the counter (called itemnumber) to create a new instance of a class and have the variable value within the instance name without having to manually type in the code to create a new instance of the class.

I also need a function which will show all instances created from that class

My aim is to run this function which creates a new instance every time a button is clicked

```
let itemnumber = 1;
```

so the code would create a instance called LineItem_1

My class is

```
function burgerlineitem (lineItemNumber, burgerTotal) {
    this.lineItemNumber = itemnumber;
    this.burgerTotal = burgerCustomTotal;
    itemnumber++
    }
```

so I need a automated way of creating this code

```
var LineItem_1 = new burgerlineitem(itemnumber, burgerCustomTotal)
```

My Code is

```
let itemnumber = 1;

function burgerlineitem (lineItemNumber, burgerTotal) {
    this.lineItemNumber = itemnumber;
    this.burgerTotal = burgerCustomTotal;
    itemnumber++
    }
```

Comment: Make variable LineItem_1 an array and fill it with a loop?

Comment: LineItem_1 is an example of an array. in theory what im try to achive is everytime the function is called it create a new instance with lineitem followed with the item number for example
var LineItem_1 = new burgerlineitem(itemnumber, burgerCustomTotal)
var LineItem_2 = new burgerlineitem(itemnumber, burgerCustomTotal)
var LineItem_3 = new burgerlineitem(itemnumber, burgerCustomTotal)

Comment: `var LineItem_1 = new burgerlineitem(itemnumber, burgerCustomTotal)` does not create an array. Please edit your question with a more detailed description of the desired result.

Comment: Im not trying to create an array. Im trying automate the create of an instance of the burgerlineitem class, so that when someone clicks on a html button and new instance of the burger lineitem class is created

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I totally get what you want, but you can do something like this. It pushes every instance of the class into an array when you click the button.

```js
itemnumber = 0;
var lineItems = [];

function burgerlineitem(lineItemNumber, burgerTotal) {
  this.lineItemNumber = lineItemNumber;
  this.burgerTotal = burgerTotal;
  itemnumber++;
}

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  lineItems.push(new burgerlineitem(itemnumber, "???"));
  
  //Create report of all items in the console.
  console.log("burgerlineitems report:");
  lineItems.forEach(function(burgerlineitem) {
    console.log("burgerlineitem: " +  burgerlineitem.lineItemNumber);
  });
  console.log("-----------");
});
```

```html
<button id="add">Create burgerline</button>
```

Comment: @HumzaYusuf yeah because i did not know what `burgerCustomTotal` was i replaced it with `"???"`. If your question is answered please accept the question so others can see you don't need help anymore.

Comment: using your code i was able to get what I need. function objectCreator(itemnumber) { new burgerlineitem(itemnumber,burgerCustomTotal) }

How would you track the instances created from the burgerlineitem class.

Comment: @HumzaYusuf you want to get the instance by `instance.lineItemNumber`?

Comment: I want to print out a list of all instances created when the objectCreator function is runs

Comment: @HumzaYusuf You can do that easily with `forEach()`. See my updated example.

Comment: @HumzaYusuf It's not meant as offensive, but looping over arrays is pretty basic stuff. You should do some research before asking. It's much better for your learning progression to find out yourself.